# Result undefined in AnuglarJS even though result is returned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pkcs#10

I have a requirement to receive values from an operation above which uses a HTML form to collect data from a user and pass it to an external JavaScript file that returns a string after processing the values. This JavaScript file has been transpiled with Babel as a bundle from ES6 which uses Promises to process the value and return the string result. Now, I've used `.then` to make AngularJS wait for the response before making a `$http` call. The result comes back but, it's not used as the value passed into my `.then` operator. Please, how do I resolve this? Below is my code snippet:

```
var numBits = $scope.getCertKeySize();
try{
    CreateRequest($scope.fields['env'], numBits).then(function(result){
        $scope.fields['key'] = result; //result comes back undefined

        var jsonMsg = $scope.fields;

        $http({
           method: 'POST',
            url: '/requestedStuff',
            data: jsonMsg,
            headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            $scope.disableSubmit = true;
        });
    });
}catch(err){
    return false;
}

function CreateRequest($scope.fields['env'], numBits){

    var fromCSForm = document.fromLiveApp;
    var userId = fromCSForm.txtUserId.value;
    var department = fromCSForm.txtDepartment.value;

    return createFromExternalJSFile(userId, department);//returns a promise with the result
}
```

This is the sample code from within createFromExternalJSFile as requested:

```
function createFromExternalJSFile(userId, department) {
  return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
    return createPKCS10Internal(userId, department);
  }).then(function () {
    var resultString = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\r\n";
    resultString = "".concat(resultString).concat(formatPEM((0, _pvutils.toBase64)((0, _pvutils.arrayBufferToString)(pkcs10Buffer))));
    resultString = "".concat(resultString, "\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\r\n");
  });
}
```

Please, forgive my ignorance as I'm not savvy with AngularJS and JavaScript as much as I could be. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code from the function `createFromExternalJSFile(userId, department)` ?

Comment: @Michael, I have added the code from that method which is a slightly modified version of the pkijs library for creating CSR. The sample code uses internal values, I just modified it to use external values instead to generate the CSR. The method finishes and responds with the CSR string but, it’s not passed into the ```result``` within the ```.then``` function.

Comment: So does this go into the `var resultString ....` block? If so this needs to return it

Comment: @Michael, if you had put this as an answer, I would have upvoted and accepted it as this solved my problem!! Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the value from your last .then function, eg:

```
function createFromExternalJSFile(userId, department) {
  return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
    return createPKCS10Internal(userId, department);
  }).then(function () {
    var resultString = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\r\n";
    resultString = "".concat(resultString).concat(formatPEM((0, _pvutils.toBase64)((0, _pvutils.arrayBufferToString)(pkcs10Buffer))));
    resultString = "".concat(resultString, "\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\r\n");
    return resultString;
  });
}
```